# Will Sitecore SE be included in the Data Explorer?

Tags: support

I want to know if the information from Sitecore SE will be available on http://data.stackexchange.com now that we are in public beta?

I have been unable to target this site so far, is there a time period we have to wait before it's available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the content for the Stack Exchange Data Explorer is updated periodically, so Sitecore SE should be included in the next update.

> #### [How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?](http://data.stackexchange.com/help)
>
> The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC.